# 'TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object', while trying to get numbers from a web page with BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to extract integers from a url with bs4. I imported re to get the numbers but I get the above error. I'm confused and would appreciate some help.

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import ssl
import re

# Ignore SSL certificate errors
ctx = ssl.create_default_context()
ctx.check_hostname = False
ctx.verify_mode = ssl.CERT_NONE

url = input('Enter - ')
html = urlopen(url, context=ctx).read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')

# Retrieve all of the anchor tags
tags = soup('span')
for tag in tags:
    re.findall('<span.*[0-9].*',tag)
```

Link http://py4e-data.dr-chuck.net/comments_314936.html
Output expected: Print the numbers from the link

Comment: Add some output and link for us to be able to help from there.

Comment: were going to type the same...

Comment: http://py4e-data.dr-chuck.net/comments_314936.html

Comment: That's the link.

Comment: It's `http` link, why are you using `ssl`?

Comment: I thought maybe I could try some HTTPS. But I now removed the ssl thing and it still gives the same error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the number directly by using `.get_text()`. And I have removed unnecessary code.

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


url = 'http://py4e-data.dr-chuck.net/comments_314936.html'
html = urlopen(url).read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')

# Retrieve all of the anchor tags
tags = soup('span')
for tag in tags:
    print(tag.get_text())
```

---

**Output:**

```
100
98
93
91
.
.
.
```

Answer (score 1):

'tag' is returned as a bs4.element.tag
That has to be received as a string to search within that.

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import ssl
import re

# Ignore SSL certificate errors
ctx = ssl.create_default_context()
ctx.check_hostname = False
ctx.verify_mode = ssl.CERT_NONE

url = input('Enter - ')
html = urlopen(url, context=ctx).read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')

# Retrieve all of the anchor tags
tags = soup('span')

for tag in tags:
    word = re.findall('(\d+)',str(tag), re.I)
    word = ''.join(word)
    print(word)
```